# Entity Framework vs SQL Injection (segurança?)

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, segurança

Olá! Sou novato em desenvolvimento então me desculpem se a pergunta for boba. Se for agradeço link's com referências para que eu possa me informar melhor.

Por mais que tenha entendido o conceito e a utilização de SQL injection não consigo ter malícia suficiente para imaginar ataques e utilizações práticas, aí fico preocupado com a segurança do meu aplicativo. Estou desenvolvendo em .NET ASP MVC com C# e acesso a dados com Entity Framework. Li que o melhor método para evitar o famigerado SQL injection é utilizar store procedures para tudo. Mas fazer isso com Entity Framework, me parece, acabaria por retirar toda a praticidade dessa ferramenta.

Então vem minha dúvida. Se faço uma entidade assim:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int ClienteID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
}
```

E crio um Controller padrão, utilizando Scaffolding onde tenho uma action Edit:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="ID,Nome,Cnpj,Telefone")] Cliente cliente)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(cliente).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(cliente);
}
```

**Estou sujeito a SQL Injection se meu usuário digitar uma cláusula Insert ou Delete no campo Nome da minha View? Se sim, como me prevenir disso?**

Vejo um monte de tutoriais e cursos ensinando assim, mas ninguém comenta sobre questões de segurança.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando usamos LINQ to Entities é livre de SQL Injection sim. Eu não tenho certeza quando ao uso de ADO.NET.

Enfim. Do jeito que está fazendo não é possível injetar códigos SQL.

Comment: Obrigado @Manaces Você entende bem de segurança? Poderia me indicar algum texto para que eu me informe melhor?

Comment: Tem a própria documentação aqui: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/security-considerations

Comment: Desde que não use nada de SQL. Segurança é algo extremamente complexo e não será um texto que ajudará muito. Na verdade costuma atrapalhar, porque é comum a pessoa ler algo e achar que já sabe o que precisa.

Comment: @bigown Kkkkk! Pois é, principalmente quando temos pressa e hoje em dia tudo parece urgente, temos que dar um jeitinho agora e "depois vemos melhor". Mas por algum lugar tenho que começar certo? Eu já até me interessei por seguir carreira em segurança de TI, mas não conheço nenhum curso ou nada que dê o caminho das pedras para isto.